# XCODE can find .app file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working on my first iOS app. It works and build correctly but when I wanna to find .app file I cant find it. My appname.app is red and I cant "show in finder". Where can be the problem that I havent developer account?

Thank you for replies.

Comment: It's in the simulator folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you run this app in the simulator from XCode:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1 (or whatever OS you run it out of XCode)/Applications
```

In here you will find some folders with random names. One of these is your app.

Answer (score 1):

1) Set your build for "iOS Device" (not simulator).
2) Product/Build.

Then you will see the .app file created.